# couldn't run Google Map Marker Cluster

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried alot added all libraries with no use and followed documentation to make it work any help would be appreciated
Here's what appear at my logcat:

```
  05-18 17:26:50.480: E/dalvikvm(5818): Could not find class 'com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.ClusteringDemoActivity', referenced from method com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.ClusteringDemoActivity
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    05-18 17:26:50.552: E/AndroidRuntime(5818):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think the library is not added correctly or the API key might be invalid for GoogleMaps you are using.
Could you please post `MainActivity.java` line 22?

Comment: addDemo("Clustering", ClusteringDemoActivity.class);

Comment: Is this class withing your source project files?